# How to find a user32.dll function address from an x64 process within an x86 process?

Tags: winapi, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, getprocaddress

How to find a user32.dll function address from an x64 process within an x86 process?

Edit: i mean my program runs x64, and i searching an x86 address.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: well.. by using another x64 child program?

Comment: i want the other process to call AllowSetForegroundWindow with my pid so i can steal his focus

Comment: What makes you think you can run 32 bit code from 64 bit code?

Comment: i dont want 32 bit code run from 64 bit code. i want inject 32 bit code into 32 bit process from 64 bit process, and i need to know a 32 bit function address for that.

Answer (score 5):

Stop it (trying to steal focus, that is).  Even though we are programmers here, we are on the side of the users.

- [The Old New Thing: The arms race between programs and users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)
- [The Old New Thing: Pressing a registered hotkey gives you the foreground activation love](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/26/9445006.aspx)

Comment: I want make my program focused when the user push some keystroke, and i need to steal focus for that. What is so special about it?

Comment: @DxCK: You can get focus from a hotkey press without injecting code into the active process.  See second linked Raymond Chen article.

Comment: I dont want using windows hotkey feature, i want something like Google Desktop Ctrl-Ctrl hotkey, i do the keyboard hooking myself.